# Cannot log-in to rstudio-server

Tags: r, macos, rstudio-server

I have previously successfully installed rstudio-server with `brew install rstudio-server` on a Mac OS X 10.11.4.

Now, I am trying to login to rstudio-server 0.99.902 without success. From the client side, I get a pop-up window saying -

> "RStudio Initialization Error", "Unable to connect to service".

The user I am using has a user id of `1100`, so I do not think the problem is related to account permissions.

While running the daemon, when I try to log-in, the error showing up in `/var/log/system.log` is this:

> rserver[1100]: ERROR system error 61 (Connection refused) [request-uri=/rpc/client_init];
> OCCURRED AT: void rstudio::core::http::LocalStreamAsyncClient::handleConnect(const boost::system::error_code &) /tmp/rstudio-server-20160803-68705-uhvyws/rstudio-0.99.902/src/cpp/core/include/core/http/LocalStreamAsyncClient.hpp:119;
> LOGGED FROM: void rstudio::server::session_proxy::(anonymous namespace)::logIfNotConnectionTerminated(const rstudio::core::Error &, const http::Request &)
> /tmp/rstudio-server-20160803-68705-uhvyws/rstudio-0.99.902/src/cpp/server/ServerSessionProxy.cpp:308

Crash report: http://pastebin.com/GYkFZ8fT

While running `sudo /usr/local/bin/rserver --server-daemonize=0`, when I try to log-in, no error is output to the console but I do get this error on a pop-up window in the browser: `Error occurred during transmission`.

Crash report: http://pastebin.com/kJMsPh6s

Additional info:

`rstudio-server verify-installation` returns `too many positional options have been specified on the command line`.

Running `sessionInfo()` from R console:

```
R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11.4 (El Capitan)

locale:
[1] C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

Comment: sounds like some good info to file as a github issue on that homebrew repo

Comment: @hrbrmstr: I am just trying to rule out configuration issues before filing an issue.

Comment: Are your using the correct port to login to Rstudio server? Should be 8787.

Comment: This might help https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/issues/3634

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[These](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/issues/3243#issuecomment-219204455) [two](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/issues/3634#issuecomment-219204048) Github issue comments point to the fact that

> RStudio Server doesn't ship with an administrative script on Mac OSX.

This was fixed [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/pull/3663).

[Updating](https://github.com/brewsci/homebrew-base/blob/master/Formula/rstudio-server.rb) your `rstudio-server` should help. Do note that you should `brew tap brewsci/base` first.